# Make a List Based on the Aggregation of Ratings from Two Models

Tags: python, django

From two models:

```
class Review(models.Model):
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  album = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  rating = models.IntegerField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)],
    default=10,
  )
  ...

class AddedReview(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  rating = models.IntegerField(default=10)
  ...
```

I was able to create a model method in the `Review` model to aggregate the `rating`s from both models above:

```
def avg_rating(self):
    added_ratings = 0
    orig_rating = self.rating
    added_ratings_count = self.addedreview_set.count()

    if added_ratings_count > 0:
      for added_review in self.addedreview_set.all():
        added_ratings += added_review.rating
        ratings_sum = added_ratings + orig_rating

      ratings_count = added_ratings_count + 1
      ratings_avg = ratings_sum / ratings_count
      avg_return = round(ratings_avg, 1)

      if avg_return == 10.0:
        avg_return = 10
      else:
        avg_return = avg_return

      return avg_return

    else:
      return self.rating
```

I have the `Review`s displayed by the date they were created, with their "Avg. Rating" displayed:

[image: Reviews in created by order]

Now I want to create a "Highest Rated" list, ordering the list by each `Review`s "Avg. Rating":

[image: Highest Rated list by average ratings]

I thought I would be able to do this using the `{{ review.avg_rating }}` I just created:

```
# views.py

highest_list = Review.objects.order_by('-avg_rating')[0:5]

# sidebar_component.html (included in home.html)

{% for review in highest_list %}
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <p class="list-item"><a href="{% url 'review' review.id %}">{{ review.artist }} - {{ review.album }}</a></p><span>{{ review.avg_rating }}</span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But this returns an error:

"FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'avg_rating' into field."

Obviously this is due to `avg_rating` not being an actual field in the `Review` model.

[image: Individual review]

[image: Form for added review]

Comment: I haven't used django in a while, but since this is a method, can't you simply call `avg_rating` in your template? `<span>{{ review.avg_rating() }}</span>`

Comment: What is the difference between `Review` and `AddedReview`?

Comment: @AdamSmith: I think it is aout the ordering, not about the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the `Review` (?) model has a rating and there is an `AddedReview` model is quite bizarre, but anyway. You can not order by a property, since the database does not know about properties. Furthermore the property requires extra queries, which is not very efficient.

You can annotate the query and order. You thus should *omit* the `avg_rating` property, and work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Sum

Review.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=(F('rating') + Sum('addedreview__rating', default=0))
    / (Count('addedreview__rating') + 1)
).order_by('-avg_rating')[:5]
```

But likely a simpler modeling where you only store ratings in the `AddedReview` model would simplify this (and might make it more efficient):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

# version if you only add ratings to the AddedReview model
Review.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('addedreview__rating')).order_by(
    '-avg_rating'
)[:5]
```

Comment: The `Review` is the original review posted by a User, and that User will be able to add a `rating` to the original review. The `AddedReview` is additional reviews or comments added by other Users to the original `Review`, and those Users will be able to add their own `rating`s to the original review.

Comment: But thank you for your response, @Willem Van Onsem!

Comment: @AndrewRea: I think you can simplify this by adding the rating to the `AddedReview` model, and for example use a boolean field, or something else to determine what the original rating is.

Comment: I tried the first bit of code you suggested: ```Review.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=(F('rating') + Sum('addedreview__rating', default=0))
    / (Count('addedreview__rating') + 1)
).order_by('-avg_rating')[:5]``` But that is only displaying the `Review.rating` and ordering the list by those `Review.rating`s. I posted two images to my original question above, which show an individual review with "AddedReview"s, and the form for a User to add an "AddedReview". As you can see, the "Avg. Rating" is the accumulation of **all** the ratings from the `Review` and the `AddedReview`s.

Comment: @AndrewRea: normally it adds the `rating` to the sum of the `ratings` of the *related* `AddedReview`s and then divides by the number of `AddedReview`s plus one. Of course if there are no `AddedReview`s for that `Review`, it will return the `rating`, since then that is the only one we have.

Comment: @AndrewRea: (a) what database do you use, and (b) what is the result of the `print(qs.query)` with `qs` the queryset. Note that you should *remove* the property/method `avg_review`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253451/discussion-between-andrew-rea-and-willem-van-onsem).